# GETDATE() function in SQL Server does not work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, getdate

For some reason the following code in my database server always returns the same value:

```
SELECT GETDATE();
```

Date and time are always the same no matter how many times I execute this code and the date and time returned **are several days behind** the real date and time.

I have tried restarting the database server and verified that the system date and time on the server host machine are correct.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and executed this query in Azure Data Studio.

This used to work, but now it does not. Do you have any tips?

Comment: `GETDATE` just gets the value from the host OS. If it's returning the wrong value then either the server has the wrong time, or something has gone *very* wrong with the underlying inbuilt binary files.

Comment: I have never heard of this (and I even looked for ways to do something like this on purpose: [{ 1 }](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/140682/1186), [{ 2 }](https://dbfiddle.uk/yVgttRAE)). Is SQL Server 2019 in a Docker container? What is the underlying OS? Have you done anything to fiddle with either the SQL Server installation or the underlying OS? What happened between "used to" and "now"? Without any solid clues I'd suggest back up your databases, completely remove SQL Server, and start over. But if the problem is in the system calls in the OS, that won't help either.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 1. Server is running Ubuntu 22. 2. Yes, MS-SQL server is running inside a Docker container. 3. No, installation command was as follows: ```sudo docker run --disable-content-trust --env "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" --env "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=PASSWORD" --env "MSSQL_PID=Developer" --env "MSSQL_LCID=1050" --publish 1433:1433 --name SPH --hostname SPH mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest```. I did not change any configuration in the OS in Docker. If I get into the Docker container, open Bash and execute ```date``` command I get the correct date and time.

Comment: I did not do any special configuration of the server after installation. Just imported the databases and that was it. And it worked for more than a year without problem. I did not change any configuration between when it last time worked and now. Only normal database operations including selecting, deleting, inserting and modifying tables.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - do `SELECT SYSDATETIME()` and `SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME()` show the same "symptoms" ?

Comment: Check if it's a caching problem 
```SELECT getdate()
OPTION(RECOMPILE)```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Both queries return correct date and time. Only ```GETDATE``` is problematic.

Comment: No, recompile option does not solve the problem.

Comment: server or database?  Does the problem follow you regardless of which database you are using?  `use database1
go
select getdate
go`
 (but not all on one line.  Too bad we can't format comments.)

Comment: SQL Server is not supported on Ubuntu. It might work, but no support.

Comment: Yes, the same problem with ```GETDATE``` happens regardless of the database I use. Even ```master```.

Comment: Yes, but that is why I run it inside Docker, so it does not matter what Operating System does host machine use.

Comment: @Charlieface you might want to tell Microsoft that. `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest bash -c "cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY_NAME"` returns `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You're right, but it's only the LTS, not the up to date release.